# Add active class to custom link on load

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

What happens is that the active link is removed on refresh, what should I do so on refresh it checks which link is on and adds the class? I believe this should be done with js, any tips are helpful thanks in advance.

I have this setup for links in my php file:

```
<?php if (!is_page('main')){  ?>
    <div class="shop-categories layoutcolor1">

        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( 21, 'product_cat' ); ?
            >">
                <p class="first"><?php echo get_cat_name( 21 ); ?> </p>

            </a>

            <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( 20, 'product_cat' ); ?
            >">
                <p class="second"><?php echo get_cat_name( 20 ); ?></p>

            </a>

            <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( 18, 'product_cat' ); ?
            >">
                <p class="third"><?php echo get_cat_name( 18 ); ?></p>

            </a>
        </li>


    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

And I have js:

```
$('.shop-categories li a').click(function() {

    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed with:

```
$('.shop-categories li a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).prop('href') === browserUrl;
}).addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var cp_url= window.location.pathname;

$('.shop-categories li').find('a').each(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('active', $(this).attr('href') == cp_url);
})
```

Comment: it does not go to the shop link it prevents from going which does not load my content

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this...

```
$('.shop-categories li a').click(function() {
   $(this).addClass('active').siblings('a').removeClass('active');
});
```